# Scala Play test can't find WSClient during dependency injection

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, dependency-injection

I'm trying to DI a class into a Unit Test, using the following:

```
val injector = new GuiceInjectorBuilder().injector()
val secured = injector.instanceOf[Secured]
```

However when I try and run it, I get the following error:

```
[info] Exception encountered when attempting to run a suite with class name: org.scalatest.DeferredAbortedSuite *** ABORTED ***
[info]   com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
[info] 
[info] 1) No implementation for play.api.libs.ws.WSClient was bound.
[info]   while locating play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
[info]     for parameter 3 at com.fredley.Secured.<init>(Secured.scala:36)
[info]   while locating com.fredley.Secured

...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `ws` in your `libraryDependencies`? xD Also, try to use Play's `play.api.Application.instanceCache[MyClass]`. See [here](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/basic/test/CatDaoSpec.scala#L21).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was not building the injector from the application (meaning Play dependencies were not loaded). This fixed the issue:

```
val application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().build
val secured = application.injector.instanceOf[Secured]
```